# Create service with arguments using SC.exe

Tags: windows-services

I've spent the last 2 hours trying every conceivable way to create a service using sc.exe and pass arguments but I can't seem to get it right.

I've read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663331/creating-a-service-with-sc-exe-how-to-pass-in-context-parameters) and all the answers about 5 times and it's been no help!

From what I read there it seems I should construct the command like this:

```
sc create MyService binPath= "C:\path\to\myservice.exe --param1=TestString"
```

My Service `OnStart` method looks like this:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    If Not IsNothing(args) Then
        Library.WriteLog("Number of args = " & args.Count)
        If args.Count > 0 Then
            For i = 0 To args.Count - 1
                Library.WriteLog("Arg" & i & ": " & args(i))
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

But everything I've tried yields "Number of Args = 0" in the log

For clarity I've tried the following (plus a few more probably):

```
sc create MyService binPath= "C:\path\to\myservice.exe --param1=TestString"
sc create MyService binPath= "C:\path\to\myservice.exe --TestString"
sc create MyService binPath= "C:\path\to\myservice.exe --param1=\"TestString\""
sc create MyService binPath= "C:\path\to\myservice.exe -param1=TestString"
sc create MyService binPath= "C:\path\to\myservice.exe -TestString"
sc create MyService binPath= "C:\path\to\myservice.exe -param1=\"TestString\""
```

I must be missing something really silly here but I'm banging my head off a wall with it!

Comment: How do you know what the `onStart` of an .**exe** binary is?  I mean, did you write the **.exe** in VB.NET yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this answer and the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6491219/724591), the `args` parameter of `OnStart` is only used when manually setting start parameters in the windows service dialog, which cannot be saved.

You can use the arguments you are setting up by accessing them in the `Main` method (located in the Service.Designer.vb file by default). Below is an example:

```
<MTAThread()> _
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
Shared Sub Main(ByVal args As String())
    Dim ServicesToRun() As System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase
    ServicesToRun = New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase() {New Service1(args)}
    System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun)
End Sub
```

You will need to add or modify a constructor to your service class to accept the arguments:

```
Private ReadOnly _arguments As String()

Public Sub New(ByVal args As String())
    InitializeComponent()
    _arguments = args
End Sub
```

Then your `OnStart` method becomes:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    If Not IsNothing(args) Then
        Library.WriteLog("Number of args = " & _arguments.Count)
        If args.Count > 0 Then
            For i = 0 To args.Count - 1
                Library.WriteLog("Arg" & i & ": " & _arguments(i))
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```