# How to start a service on 'Windows Server 2019' with 'start parameters' automatically?

Tags: windows-server-2019

How to start a service on 'Windows Server 2019' with 'start parameters' automatically?
That is, whenever 'Windows Server 2019' is restarted, this service will run and should read the 'start parameter' automatically.

I already informed a value in the 'start parameter' and when doing the start manually it worked, but as the 'start parameter' does not persist, when the 'Windows 2019 Server' is restarted again it runs the service without the 'start parameter 'start'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a Windows service with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243753/how-to-make-a-windows-service-with-parameters)

Comment: I made changes to edit the registry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\ , but it gave an error when starting the service, as if it did not accept the parameter in that location.

Comment: "*it gave an error*"? What error? And have you restarted your machine, because the service control manager keeps the configuration in memory and only reads from the registry at startup

Comment: Or you could use the [`SC.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-config) utitlity to set the binpath of your service instead of editing the registry

Comment: There is a respective question on [Superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/1507269/can-i-pass-parameters-to-a-windows-service-through-gpo)